# Ng-Switch not Working properly with String.length - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, string-length, ng-switch

I'm working on a Store application and I need to show 2 different strings based on a response.

If I receive the response with no item title I need to show "No Item Title Found", else, I need to show item's title limited to a certain amount of characters.

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-switch on="item.title">
  <div ng-switch-when="!item.title.length">
    <p class="prod-title cursor-pointer" 
       ng-click="searchCtrl.openItemTab(item,event)">
         {{ item.title = 'Title Not Found'}}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
    <p class="prod-title cursor-pointer" 
       ng-click="searchCtrl.openItemTab(item,event)">
         {{ item.title | limitTo:60 }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I'm able to see Items titles when their length is greater than 0, but, I'm not able to see "No Item Title Found" when length is equal to 0.**

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you replace `{{ item.title = 'Title Not Found'}}` with `Title Not Found`

Comment: I already tried both Title not found and {{Title Not Found}} without success.

Comment: even though you were able to get ng-if to work, you should note that ng-switch-when does not allow for expressions, like koox00 said. It must be a literal value to compare with. I would guess that when you expected your title length to be zero, it was in fact a null value causing things to blow up. The ng-if solution is actually checking if the property is null and not if the length is zero...But glad you have a solution now.

Comment: @TSmith `ng-switch-when` can't be an expression but `ng-switch on` can have an expression, see [ngSwich](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

Comment: @koox03 I know that. My comment doesn't contradict how ng-switch works.

Comment: Oh sorry @TSmith, I didn't notice the `-when` and took your comment the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ng-if directive to show 'Title not found' when you don't have an available title.

```
<p ng-if='!item.title' class="prod-title cursor-pointer" ng-click="searchCtrl.openItemTab(item,event)">
         Title Not Found
</p>

<p ng-if='item.title' class="prod-title cursor-pointer" ng-click="searchCtrl.openItemTab(item,event)">
             {{item.title}}
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `ng-switch` like:

```
<div ng-switch on="item.title.length">
    <div ng-switch-when="0">
```

Currently what you have means
if `item.title` (expression) equals true `(!item.title.length == item.title)` enter the first block
in any other case enter the second.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzoIEoo0QCpJxhdlQ7uK?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but, It does not seem to work.

Comment: It seems to work in the Plunker but not in my application. Look at what @TSmith wrote above.

Comment: I cannot see why it wouldn't work in your application..Anyway I was just pointing out the flaw in your logic, @fablexis solution is best for your case as you have only one condition :)